# How to sort array without using sort method in C#

Tags: c#

How to sort array without using sort method in C#

Comment: Definitely some missing context here...

Comment: @Marc - Maybe a homework assignment to learn how to implement sorting by hand?

Comment: aman - you'll find all sorts (boom boom) of detailed answers coming your way if you give a better description of the problem. if it is indeed homework, it's no shame to ask for help. just make sure to add the homework tag and you'll be respected for it.

Answer (score 5):

[Visualization and Comparison of sorting algorithms in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/SortVisualization.aspx)

example code

```
public IList BubbleSort(IList arrayToSort)
{
    int n = arrayToSort.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (int j = n; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (((IComparable)arrayToSort[j - 1]).CompareTo(arrayToSort[j]) > 0)
            {
                object temp = arrayToSort[j - 1];
                arrayToSort[j - 1] = arrayToSort[j];
                arrayToSort[j] = temp;
                         }
        }
    }
    return arrayToSort;
}
```

above will surely helps you to understand the thing you want

Comment: Bubblesort is definitely best suggestion! (ironically) :)

Comment: Bubblesort is definitely a bad algorithm, and should not be used for anything else than educational use (for those who don't understand irony)...

Answer (score 1):

By assigning value by value in alphabetical or whatever order.

Sorry, but I don't get your question. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to sort the array without using array sort method. if you know please give some code hints

Comment: Try this one: [Bubble Sort](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4461).

Comment: @Aman - I think we have understood what you want. But we can't understand why in the world you would like to do such a thing!

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loop sorting methods such as bubble sort.

But why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Don't use bubblesort, and never-ever recommend someone to use it, it's a bad algorithm...

Comment: @Quandary: We all know it's bad, but the PO was looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use the `OrderBy` extention method on `IEnumerable` to sort it.

If your question is how to do it without using any built in functionality in the framework, I guess I will have to ask. **Why??**