# odd/even numbers - sort array

Tags: c#

Can anyone help. I have to write a program that lets the user input 10 numbers. And sort those numbers in odd(ascending order) and even(descending order).

for example: 
input: 2, 8, 7, 13, 23, 9, 34, 11, 1, 16
output: 1, 7, 9, 11, 13, 23, 34, 16, 8, 2

And I have to do this without any methods, such as Array.Sort.

This is my code so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input 10 numbers: ");
        int[] number = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++) {
            number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (number[i] == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("input of 0 is not alllowed!");
                break;
            }
        }

        //EVEN NUMBERS
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++) {
            if (number[i] % 2 == 0) {
                Console.Write("{0} ", number[i]);
            }
        }

        //ODD NUMBERS
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++) {
            if (number[i] % 2 != 0) {
                Console.Write("{0} ", number[i]);
            }
        }
```

I just need a general idea of how to do it.

Comment: Do they have to remain in the same array or can you put them in two separate arrays?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i'd refer them in the same, but they can be in separate arrays too.

Comment: Your current logic won't be valid if the user enters "0"  10 times. So if "0" is not allowed, then you shouldn't store it in number[], right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192433/how-to-sort-array-without-using-sort-method-in-c-sharp also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758527/sorting-string-values-without-using-any-method-function ...Google is your friend

Comment: This sounds like homework. Try thinking about this not as a single problem, but two smaller, independent problems: you have two "kinds" of numbers.  and then each kind will be sorted.  As numbers are input, it's like a package coming down the conveyor belt... what "worker functions" do you need to properly filter and sort?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of good sorting algorithms that you can implement, which I won't get into since that is somewhat off topic to your question, but [here's a link](http://betterexplained.com/articles/sorting-algorithms/) to a page that describes many of them.

The key to solving your problem with any sorting algorithm will be having a good comparison function that can tell you what order the values should show up in. The important rules for that comparison in your case are:
1. Odd should always come before even
2. Lower Odd numbers should come before Higher Odd numbers
3. Higher Even numbers should come before Lower Even numbers

Therefore, your comparison function could look something like the following (note: I wouldn't name the function or parameters this way normally, but it makes it somewhat more clear for this example)

```
public bool AComesBeforeB(int a, int b) 
{
    if(IsOdd(a))
    {
        if(IsOdd(b))
        {
            return a < b;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(isOdd(b))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return a > b;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do it as yyttr3 has recommended, and split the even and odd numbers into different arrays and then sorting them from there. I prefer not to do it that way because it takes more code and more memory, but it works basically just as well.

A couple more notes not directly related to your question:

1. Look into what happens if someone does enter a 0 (hint, it doesn't run correctly)
2. Based on your code and your sample input you are assuming that the input will always be a series of integers, what happens if the user puts in a number with a decimal? Or an alphabetical string? (hint: an exception would crash your program)
3. Make sure your program handles negative numbers, as it stands right now I don't see why it wouldn't, but that is always a good test when dealing with number inputs
4. This looks like a homework assignment, and while it is fine to ask for advice and help on specific parts of a problem, don't try to use SO to do your homework for you, to be clear I don't think you're doing that, but Rariolu's answer is basically giving you the code wholesale, which could be considered plagerism if submitted as your own work
5. When you say you want to do this "without any methods", that betrays a misunderstanding of what a method is. This code will inherently be running inside a method, and in order to write this code in a clear and understandable way you will want to write your own methods that you can call from the main method. What I think you really mean to say is "I have to do with without using an of the C# library methods that are normally used for sorting".

Comment: I currently don't have the necessary reputation to comment on other people's answers so I'll comment it here. Since Alli is trying to learn how to approach this kind of problem, just giving him/her the code that does the work is counter productive. It is far more useful to provide guidance and then let Alli figure out how to actually implement the solution. This is particularly true if, as I mention in my answer, this is a homework assignment

Answer (score 0):

This should work:(bear in mind that "numbers" is an array with all the numbers inside.

```
List<int> oddnumbers = new List<int>();
List<int> evennumbers = new List<int>();
foreach(int number in numbers)
{
    if(numer % 2 == 0)//If number is divisible by 2(is even)
    {
        evennumbers.Add(number);
    }
    else//If number is not divisible by 2(is odd)
    {
        oddnumbers.Add(number);
    }
}
evennumbers = evennumbers.Sort();
oddnumbers = oddnumbers.Sort();//Sort both lists so that they values are in ascending order.
evennumbers = evennumbers.Reverse();//Reverse the items in "evennumbers" into descending order.
List<int> newnumbersequence = new List<int>();
foreach(int number in oddnumbers)
{
    newnumbersequence.Add(number);
}
foreach(int number in evennumbers)
{
    newnumbersequence.Add(number);
}
```

And then put these in a static class

```
public static List<int> Sort(this List<int> numbers)
{
    int[] temp = numbers.ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length-1; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        while(index > -1)
        {
            if (temp[index] > temp[index+1])
            {
                int num1 = temp[index];
                int num2 = temp[index+1];
                temp[index] = num2;
                temp[index+1] = num1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp.ToList();
}

public static List<int> Reverse(this List<int> numbers)
{
    List<int> returner = new List<int>();
    for(int i = numbers.Count-1; i > -1; i++)
    {
        returner.Add(numbers[i]);
    }
    return returner;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a solution that doesn't use library funtions (ie. .Sort() or .Reverse() )

Comment: Thanks but can't use library functions. If I could it wouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: I changed it to include my own ones ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps when thinking about how to implement this code:

- Split the array into two arrays, one containing odd numbers and one containing even numbers
- Create a single method that sorts an array in ascending order
- sort both arrays with this function, but reverse the order of the even array.

In pseudocode it would look similar to this:

```
//Array you get from the user
arr = get_user_inputs()
def split(array) :
  even = []
  odd  = []
  for item in array:
     if( item %2 == 0):
         even.append(item)
     else:
         odd.append(item)
  return (even,odd)

(even,odd) = split(arr)
(even,odd) = ( sort(even) , sort(odd) )
print(odd.toString + even.toString.reverse)
```

In order to implement the sort algorithm itself I would suggest looking up some simple sorting algorithms such as selection sort.

There is a video from CS50 on youtube explaining this algorithm that does a really good job:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8hXR_Hvybo

Answer (score 0):

Check that your input doesn't crash if you type a letter...

number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

You are successfully detecting ODD/EVEN numbers but you will need to store these in an intermediate array before printing out.

You have two approaches,

## 1

1. Take lowest odd number, remove from input list and add to new list.
2. Repeat until no odd numbers left
3. Take highest even number, remove from input list and add to new list.
4. Repeat until no even numbers left
5. Print out new list

## 2 (working with what you've got)

1. Create a list to store odd numbers and one for even numbers.
2. Add your numbers to the appropriate list (odd/even) as you find them (rather than print to console like you're currently doing).  Also add in required order.  E.g. for length of list, if number is greater than item at i then insert at i.
3. Print out both lists

Answer (score 0):

I would first put split the numbers into two lists (yes, I would use lists instead of arrays), and then create a `BubbleSort` function that takes a direction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

If that link is insufficient, you should be able to find plenty of implementation links to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly pseudocode, showing how the work can be broken down.

```
// initial conditions
evens = new List  // standard C# List<T> interface
odds = new List
i = 0;

// read numbers
while (i++ < 10) {
  filter(input);
}

print(odds, evens)
```

And here are the "worker" functions:

```
// decide if it goes to the even or odd:
filter(input) {
  if(input % 2 == 0) {
     // sort descending
     sort(evens, input, "desc");
  } else {
     sort(odds, input, "asc");
  }
}

// given a list, a new input to add, and direction,
// the function mutates the list accordingly
sort(list, input, direction) {
  for(j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    item = list[j];
    if((direction == "desc" && item < input) 
       || (direction == "asc" && item > input))
    {
      list.insert(j, input);
      return
    }
  }
  list.add(input);  // lastly, if nothing else was triggered
```

I suppose the most important missing piece is the sort algorithm.  Above, I've implemented a variation of [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) that uses the `List.insert` method as a shortcut for shifting the already-sorted portion of the "array".